# BadGateway exception adding SQL connector to Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, connector

When I try to add a SQL Server connector to my Logic App I get an error stating "Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: BadGateway More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is 'xx-x--xxxxx--xxx'."

[image: Sql Server Connector]

I have Contributor access for the Logic App resource. When I try to add a new API Connection or if I try to use an existing connection it throws the same permission error.

Can anyone help me here to understand what additional access/permission is required to access this connector in a Logic App?

Note: My SQL database is on Azure not on-prem.

Answer (score 1):

What caused this for me was calling a scalar valued function in a stored procedure block instead of ... a stored procedure. Once I switched to an actual stored proc everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

We have reproduced the same from our end and checked the same. You are receiving this error is might be due to any of the following reasons.

- The firewall settings that you have arranged.
- Connection settings while adding the `SQL SERVER` Connector.

> The firewall settings that you have arranged.

For this you can go to your Firewall settings from overview pane and set the start and end ip addresses.
[image]
[image]

> Connection settings while adding the `SQL SERVER` Connector.

For this make sure while you are adding Authentication type for the connector to give correct credentials.
[image]

For better results, make sure you are choosing `Use both SQL and Azure AD authentication` while creating SQL SERVER and set admin credentials for both SQL and Azure AD Authentication types so that you can use any of the either options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I tried It but didn't help me to resolve my error.  Finally I dig into more on this and Identified the setting under firewall "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server firewall setting " was set as NO. I changed it to Yes and it worked.