# Azure Logic Apps SQL Connector Error: Bad Request

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using the SQL Connector in Azure Logic Apps to connect to our Azure SQL Database to perform queries, update tables, and execute stored procedures. After several months of developing logic apps, I'm seeing the below error message when using the SQL Connector "Execute Stored Procedure (V2)". I'm only encountering this error with this specific connector. All the other connectors work just fine. Has anyone encountered this error before and had success troubleshooting?

**Error:**
Could not retrieve values. Error code: 'BadRequest', Message: 'The value's length for key 'application name' exceeds it's limit of '128'.
clientRequestId: 'XXXXX'. More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is 'XXXXX'.

Comment: check this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69793873/badgateway-exception-adding-sql-connector-to-logic-app) if it helps?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Thank you but this thread references a different issue related to accessing the Azure SQL DB from logic apps. I have no problem accessing the Azure SQL DB from Logic Apps and can query and update tables. The issue is isolated to specifically the 'Execute Stored Procedure (V2)' connector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a call with Microsoft Support and got confirmation: this is the global issue in the SQL connector of LogicApp. They are working on this to fix, no ETA for now.

Update: should be fixed from around 29.03.2022 03:00 CET

Comment: Thanks, I'm seeing this issue has fixed as well by Microsoft.